# Quartz: Based on configured schedule, the given trigger will never fire

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am getting the "Based on configured schedule, the given trigger will never fire" error when scheduling my job. I have tried adding ".startNow()" to the trigger, but that didn't solve it. I don't understand what I have done wrong.

```
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(DeploymentJob.class)
        .withIdentity(scheduleName)
        .usingJobData("uploadLocation", deployment.getUploadDir())
        .build();

// Add the job to the Scheduler
scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);

// Create the trigger with cron expression
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
       .withIdentity(scheduleName)
       .withSchedule(cronSchedule(cron))
       .forJob(jobDetail)
       .build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);                  <--- Problem line.

scheduler.start();
```

Thanks in advance for the answers! Much appreciated!

Comment: What does cronSchedule(cron) return?

Comment: It returns CronScheduleBuilder

Comment: The cron string is built based on the date/time the user selects on the frontend. It will always be a "single run" event.

    Example: 2012-07-23 15:30:00
    Cron: 0 30 3 23 7 ? 2012

Comment: Shouldn't that be 0 30 15 23 7 ? 2012

Comment: You are correct! Not sure how I missed that, sigh. Thanks. I am now fighting with a different error, but let me spend some time on it myself before asking here.

Comment: Hello @Nick, I have 0 48 15 10 1 ? 2020 of ONCE type which fire at At 15:48:00pm, on the 10th day, in January, in 2020. Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong here, as I am getting the same message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting time is beyond reach.Spring Quartz never execute the task which time is beyond reach.So change your setting time.

Comment: What is the limit?

Comment: What do you mean by beyond reach, what is the limit?